# Word association or category snap card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I played a game once at a games night that was something like snap, except the cards had categories on them and instead of saying "snap" you had to say a word in that category (if I remember rightly. It may have been word association). I think if the card was the same colour as the previous card, or had the same symbol, you could try to "snap". Does anyone know the name of this game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might it have been [Anomia](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/67877/anomia)? In Anomia, cards have categories and symbols on them, and when two cards with the same symbol are visible the people with those cards have to name something that belongs to the category on the *other* player's card. Whoever does that first then takes the other player's card, which may then reveal another card which matches someone else's, and so on.